# did select annotation for multiple markers

Tags: iphone, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am adding multiple markers in the map view like this,

```
markers = [jsonDict objectForKey:key];
            for (id k in markers) {

                if ([k isEqualToString:@"latitude"]) {

                    mlat = [markers objectForKey:k];
                    dlat = [mlat doubleValue];
                }

                else if ([k isEqualToString:@"longitude"]) {

                    mlng = [markers objectForKey:k];
                    dlng = [mlng doubleValue];
                }


                else if ([k isEqualToString:@"file"]){
                    murl = [markers objectForKey:k];
                }

                else if ([k isEqualToString:@"comment"]){
                    mcomment = [markers objectForKey:k];
                }

            }
            annotationCoord.latitude = dlat;
            annotationCoord.longitude = dlng;
            MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
            [self.navimap addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
```

now, i would like to get the value of "`comment`" and "`file`" for each marker in the `didSelectAnnotationView`. it would be grateful if anybody helps me in this.

Comment: Hi, create a class by subclassing MKAnnotationView class. Create some property values inside. So that you can access in delegate method while you tap on any pin. Post this as a question. In comments, code cannot be added. Regards, Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a custom annotation class and use it rather than MKPointAnnotation:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Marker : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* url;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* comment;

@end
```

You would then implement `didSelectAnnotationView` like this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{        
    if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[Marker class]]) {
        Marker* marker = view.annotation;
        NSLog(@"selected marker %@", marker);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly for me!! thank you so much and sorry for the late response.